# jQuery Object literal function declaration error

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, syntax-error

I am wondering what is wrong with this code, it throws a *Syntax Error: unexpected token "anotherFuction* if I add the `anotherFunction` part. Can someone please explain why, JavaScript is confusing me so much with all this different ways calling functions.

```
var ajax = {

        parseJSONP : function(result) {
            console.log(result)

            //iterate each returned item
            $.each(result.items, function(i, row) {
                $('#listview_test').append('<li><a href="#headline"><img src="' + row.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail + '" class="ui-li-has-thumb"/><h3>' + row.volumeInfo.title + '</h3></a></li>');
            });
            //end iteration of data returned from server and append to the list
            $('#listview_test').listview('refresh');
            // refresh the list-view so new elements are added to the DOM
        }

        //error is here, I just wanted to add another function here to do 
         something

        anotherFuction : function(){

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting the `,` after the closing `}` of the first member in the object literal.

You need to separate each member, as shown below:

```
var ajax = {    
        parseJSONP : function(result) {
            $.each(result.items, function(i, row) {
                $('#listview_test').append('<li><a href="#headline"><img src="' + row.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail + '" class="ui-li-has-thumb"/><h3>' + row.volumeInfo.title + '</h3></a></li>');
            });
            $('#listview_test').listview('refresh');
        },
      // ^ Here   
       anotherFuction : function(){
           // No more syntax errors!
       }   
}
```

Comment: Is there any benefit or why we declare functions like this ? I don't mean the coma, but inside object literals

Comment: @DaimanLoks Yes, but I can't explain it as well as Douglas Crockford. Please see the Invocation section (chap 4.3.1) in his book, JavaScript - the good parts. You can view it online for free - http://eleventyone.done.hu/OReilly.JavaScript.The.Good.Parts.May.2008.pdf

Answer (score 1):

When you use the "Object Literal Syntax", e.g.:

```
var object = {};
```

You have to separate all "members" (variables, functions) with a comma (`,`).

So your code will become:

```
var ajax = {
   parseJSONP: function(result) { /* function body from above */ },
   something,
   anotherFunction: function() {}
}
```

notice the addition of the commas (`,`) after `something` and `parseJSONP`.